# how can we change tooltip(title attribure) font and color in asp.net projects?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, colors, tooltip, title

how can we change tooltip(title attribure) font and color in asp.net with c# projects?

there is another thread in stackoverflow without any answer (so sorry for duplicate)

thanks in advance

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tooltip colour that displays the `title` attribute is a browser default and can't be changed.

However, you could create your own 'tool tip' in JavaScript using an `onmouseover()` event.

jQuery makes this easy and there are 3rd-party controls available too.